# c# Assert.AreEqual not workng

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mstest, assert

I am playing around with unit testing on Visual Studio.

Trying to test a simple call

```
Assert.AreEqual(2, 1, 2);
```

When run the test, it say pass? Shouldn't it be failed.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not using Assert.AreEqual(2, 1)? Specifying three numbers lets you specify an accuracy to the check. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.assert.areequal.aspx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458.aspx

The third parameter in `Assert.AreEqual(double, double, double)` specifies the degree of accuracy you want for equality. Your code asks "is 2 within 2 of 1" which it certainly is.

Comment: Two addenda:

1. I really encourage NUnit instead of the built in visual studio unit test framework.

2. There isn't a built in extension method for `Assert` which tests an arbitrary list of parameters, but it's pretty easy to write one that (I have a homebrew little package that has a bunch of things like Assert.AllEqual(), Assert.NoneEqual etc.) Take a crack at it!

Comment: Regarding your addenda: 1. Very subjective. MSTest is perfectly fine for most scenarios. If you're going for a third party testing framework then you might as well take xUnit.NET which will be the replacement of MSTest in the next VS. 2. There's always [CollectionAssert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.testtools.unittesting.collectionassert.aspx).

Comment: @JeroenVannevel There are also http://www.fluentassertions.com/ which give you more readable `2.Should().Be(1)` statements than `Assert.AreEqual(2,1)`

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Fully agree, FA is one of my standard nuget packages ;) I was more referring to what's inside MSTest but it's true that FA is much more expressive and provides more comparisons.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel. Yep, very subjective.

Answer (score 4):

You are calling [Assert.AreEqual Method (Double, Double, Double)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms243458.aspx) with `double delta=2`, so indeed difference between 2 and 1 is less than 2.

You probably want

```
Assert.AreEqual(2,1, "Expected {0}", 2);
```

Comment: I think this is arguably the _better_ answer because not only does it describe the cause, but also shows a _fix_. +1